# How to find out server response code using java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

How can we identify the server response code through java coding. I mean if we got any response from server as a HTTP response, we should be able to print this as string or whatever. Also, I wanted to know how do we track in java, if some particular request is being hit to the server and find out the server response code too.

Comment: Would you like to be more specific, like are you using HttpClient or URLConnection, or maybe your own implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I am using the HttpClient for making the request

Comment: Then you can call HttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() for getting the status code: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html

Comment: Please edit your question @aditi and provide more details about HttpClient.  Show some code.  I know you have your answer now but this is for others with the same question.

Comment: @ahanin Please make your comment an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [HttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getStatusCode%28%29) for getting the status code: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html

And for getting response entity you call [HttpResponse.getEntity()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicHttpResponse.html#getEntity%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

In Java and in the case that you want access to the http header code, you can use this :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
HttpURLConnection openConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
openConnection.connect();
int rCode = openConnection.getResponseCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use URLConnection then this code help you and you can able to print HTTP response as string.

```
String output = null;
output = getHttpResponseRabby("input url link");

public static String getHttpResponseRabby(String location) {

    String result = "";
    URL url = null;
    Log.d("http:", "balance information");

    try {
        url = new URL(location);
        Log.d("http:", "URL Link" + url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("http:", "URL Not found" + e.getMessage());
    }

    if (url != null) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in;
            HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            while(true)
            {
                try 
                    {
                     in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                    } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        break;
                    }


                String inputLine;

                int lineCount = 0; // limit the lines for the example
                while ((lineCount < 5) && ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)) 
                    {
                        lineCount++;

                        result += inputLine;
                    }

                in.close();
                urlConn.disconnect();
                return result;
           }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("http:", "Retrive data" + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("http:", "FAILED TO RETRIVE DATA" + " url NULL");
    }
    return result;
}
```